# Как правильно закрыть поток ввода/вывода BufferedReader?

Tags: java, поток-ввода

Подскажите как правильно закрыть поток ввода/вывода BufferedReader
вот код:

```
BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        reader.close();
    }
```

так не работает, т.к. он может и не существовать
в каком месте правильно будет вставить код его закрытия или можно как-то проверить , что он существует?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: тут создание потока вынесено из секции try
а если понадобиться перехватить и это исключение?

Comment: *Prior to Java SE 7, you can use a finally block to ensure that a resource is closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly.*

Comment: что то я вас не пойму, я знаю, что блок finally отработает, только компилятор ругается на reader, т.к. этой переменной может не существовать

Comment: Ругается, потому что инициализация происходит у вас в блоке try

Answer (score 1):

```
try( BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) ) {
    ...
catch (Exception e){
    e.getStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: так тоже не работает,
компилятор так же ругается на reader в блоке finally

Comment: правильно ругается, вам не нужен блок finally при такой конструкции

Comment: а компилятор вам ругается потому, что у вас область видимости переменной reader  теперь только внутри блока try

Comment: При такой конструкции блок try гарантирует закрытие всех ресурсов открытых в круглых скобках

Comment: @alex почитайте про `try with resources`